# outlook vba application.goto

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

in Outlook 2010 I have such instruction in my VBA code , just for put selection to A1 and then save the Excel workbook

```
With wbFm.Sheets(1)
.................
  LastrOn = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AQ").End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 6 To LastrOn
  Val = .Cells(i, 43).Value

  Set FoundCell = .Columns("A").Find(Val)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then

    .Cells(i, 44).Copy
    .Cells(FoundCell.Row, 14).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues    <---- last cell picked up
    end if

     .................................
   Next
 .Range("AQ4") = "text1"
 .Range("AU4") = "tekst2"
End With

wbFm.Application.Goto wbFm.Sheets(1).Range("A1"),True

Fdest = emailfolder & Filedest & RepDate & ".xlsx"

If fsob.fileexists(Fdest) = False Then
  wbFm.SaveAs Fdest
 End If
  ........
```

wbFm is opened workbook

after upgrade to Outlook 2013 this command

```
wbFm.Application.Goto wbFm.Sheets(1).Range("A1"),True
```

is not working any more.
When I delete this command, program finishes properly, but the cursor when I open the saved file is on the last picked cell.
Any ideas?, regards, Ann

Answer (score 1):

Assuming wbFm is an Excel workbook object, you can simply select the cell. No need for the GoTo statement.

```
wbFm.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: This is obvious, but this command (I'm really surprise) does the same thing - end the program without saving file

Comment: I need more context to know if this is really the problem, but I see that you're checking to see if the file exists and then saving it. What if it already exists? Shouldn't you "Save" the workbook if it does exist and the "Save As" when it doesn't?